# How do I add leader titles and tails to a large batch of videos with Final Cut Pro?

Tags: video, batch, final-cut-pro

I have around 250 videos, all in the same pixel size.

I've been asked to add a leader (with title and date) and a tail with copyright information.
The title and date changes depending on the video, they are all located in an Excel sheet (and could possible be put in a xml document)

What would be the best way to approach this? Batching, automater?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a shell script for it.

1. Export the text data to a csv file
2. Use ImageMagick to generate a TIFF (or other still image) for each leader and tail.
3. Use ffmpeg to concatenate these with the videos.